# IOS device not registered for firebase notification but the same code working for android

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

[Error you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aGdP.png)

Error:

> [messaging/unregistered] You must be registered for remote messages before calling getToken, see messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages().

My JS code:

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

export const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
        console.log('Authorization status:', enabled);
        getFcmToken()
    }
}

export const getFcmToken = async () => {
    try {
        const token = await messaging().getToken({ senderId: "727807064485" });
        console.log(token, ' TOKEN');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("FCM error:", error)
    }
}
```

My Pod file configuration according to [Firebase documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/).

[Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks5o1.png)

[AppDelegate.mm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4jeP.png)

Firebase working properly with android, But in IOS this code working only for request permission and give error when I'm trying to getToken() with auto-enabled for device register configuration with adding any firsbase.json file.

[React Native Project info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRIcP.png)

FireBase package version:

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.0",
```

Tried to:-

1. Add firebase.JSON file to disable auto register and try to manual register device but its not working,
2. delete build folder,
3. npm start --reset-cache,
4. reinstall pods,
5. Re-open project in Xcode,

Comment: Is "Auto Registration" disabled in the app? See this for reference: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#auto-registration-ios

Comment: I resolve it yesterday. The issue was with Xcode capabilities (Push Notification) and added certificates in key Chain again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what fixed it was adding the `Background fetch` and `Remote notifications` in `Signing & Capabilities` in the Xcode project. It is unfortunate that the error message does not give you any idea of what went wrong. I found this out by reading the manual iOS setup guide for Firebase Messaging.

[image]

Comment: I already did. I followed the issue on github :https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6829 But nothing seems to work